# How many write operation can be blocked in chan

Tags: go, channel

I use `chan` for goroutines to write/read, if the `chan` is full, the writing goroutines will be blocked until another goroutine read from the `chan`.

I know there is a `recvq` and `sendq` double linked list in `chan` to record blocked goroutines. My question is how many goroutines totally can be blocked if `chan` is not read?  Does this depend on memory size?

Comment: plz write a descriptive answer with more detail on what u want to talk about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:** as long as your app can fit into memory and can run, you won't have any problems with channel waiting queues.

The language spec does not limit the number of waiting goroutines for a channel, so there's no practical limit.

The runtime implementation might limit the waiting goroutines to an insignificant high value (e.g. due to pointer size, integer counter size or the likes), but to reach such an implementation limit, you would run out of memory much-much sooner.

Goroutines are lightweight threads, but they do require a small memory. They start with a small stack which is around a KB, so even if you estimate it to 1 KB, if you have a million goroutines, that's already 1 GB memory at least, and if you have a billion goroutines, that's 1 TB. And a billion is nowhere near to the  max value of an `int64` for example.

Your CPU and Go runtime would have trouble managing billions of goroutines earlier than running into implementation specific waiting queue limits.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it depends on the memory. It depends on the len of channel as mentioned in the docs, a buffered channel is blocked once the chan is full, and gets unblocked, when another value is added to the chan. [channels](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#channels)

Code snippet from docs:

```
var sem = make(chan int, MaxOutstanding)

func handle(r *Request) {
    sem <- 1    // Wait for active queue to drain.
    process(r)  // May take a long time.
    <-sem       // Done; enable next request to run.
}

func Serve(queue chan *Request) {
    for {
        req := <-queue
        go handle(req)  // Don't wait for handle to finish.
    }
}
```

Once MaxOutstanding handlers are executing process, any more will block trying to send into the filled channel buffer, until one of the existing handlers finishes and receives from the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how many goroutines totally can be blocked if chan is not read?

All of them.